Merge two internal tables using comprehensions?
I'm trying to create an internal table assembled from the lines of two internal tables of the same type using table comprehension syntax. Seems simple but I can't do it:
data(lt_fcat1) = VALUE lvc_t_fcat( ).
data(lt_fcat2) = VALUE lvc_t_fcat( ).

data(lt_fcat) = VALUE lvc_t_fcat( for i in lt_fcat1 ( i )
                                  for j in lt_fcat2 ( j ) ).

Gives a syntax error:

Unknown component "for" (on the second for).


Do you want all lines of both tables?

LINES OF: data(lt_fcat) = VALUE lvc_t_fcat( ( LINES OF t_fcat1 ) ( LINES OF t_fcat2 ) ). You may also have a for iteration: ... LINES OF VALUE #( FOR ... ) ....

Thanks. Is it impossible to use two consecutive for statements for table comprehension (for example if the two tables had a different type) ?

Still the same answer: ( LINES OF VALUE #( FOR <line> IN table_of_different type ( convert_to_target_type ) ) ).

Thanks. Could you post your first comment as an answer so I can accept it please ?

Hello @SandraRossi thank you for your answer, could you post it as an answer please ?

@cutter It's done.

You need to prefix your internal table with LINES OF:
data(lt_fcat) = VALUE lvc_t_fcat( ( LINES OF t_fcat1 )
                                  ( LINES OF t_fcat2 ) ).

If you want to use a for iteration (for ... with or without where ...), you still need LINES OF:
...
( LINES OF VALUE #( FOR <line> IN itab WHERE ( AnyConditionYouWant ) ( <line> ) ) )
...

Of course, there are many other possibilities by nesting other constructor expressions (REDUCE, CORRESPONDING, etc.)
